# DdlTransactionIsolatorJtaImpl could not locate TransactionManager

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

So, I've been trying for many days to run my project, without success.
Spring Boot + Hibernate + JPA. Oracle database.
Can anybody help me?

config.properties:

```
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=validate
```

application.properties:

```plain
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
spring.datasource.username=data_integration
spring.datasource.password=secret
```

My pom.xml:

```xml
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.16.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.16.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
            <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <version>8.5.29</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>ua.com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
            <version>12.1.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.transaction-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

MyApplicationConfig.java

```java
package com.eximb.crmon;

import java.util.Properties;

import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ViewResolverRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:config.properties")
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableWebMvc

public class ApplicationConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

@Value("${hibernate.dialect}")
private String sqlDialect;

@Value("${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}")
private String hbm2ddlAuto;

@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(DataSource dataSource, JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter) {

    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    entityManagerFactory.setJtaDataSource(dataSource);
    entityManagerFactory.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter);
    entityManagerFactory.setJpaProperties(addProperties());
    entityManagerFactory.setPackagesToScan("com.eximb.crmon");

    return entityManagerFactory;

}

@Bean
public JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter() {

    HibernateJpaVendorAdapter adapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    adapter.setShowSql(true);
    adapter.setDatabasePlatform(sqlDialect);

    return adapter;

}

@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory emf){

    return new JpaTransactionManager(emf);

}


private Properties addProperties() {

    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", hbm2ddlAuto);

    return properties;

}

@Override
public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry viewRegistry) {

    viewRegistry.jsp("/WEB-INF/pages/", ".jsp");

}

@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry resourceRegistry) {

    resourceRegistry.addResourceHandler("/static_content/**").addResourceLocations("/WEB-INF/static_content/");

}
}
```

StackTrace:

```plain
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [com/eximb/crmon/ApplicationConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1710)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:583)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:502)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1085)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:858)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:752)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:388)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1246)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1234)
        at com.eximb.crmon.Application.main(Application.java:9)
        ... 6 more
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.persistenceException(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:970)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:895)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:57)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:388)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:377)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1769)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1706)
        ... 22 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: DdlTransactionIsolatorJtaImpl could not locate TransactionManager to suspend any current transaction; base JtaPlatform impl (org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform@589acbb1)?
        at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jta.internal.DdlTransactionIsolatorJtaImpl.<init>(DdlTransactionIsolatorJtaImpl.java:46)
        at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jta.internal.JtaTransactionCoordinatorBuilderImpl.buildDdlTransactionIsolator(JtaTransactionCoordinatorBuilderImpl.java:46)
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.HibernateSchemaManagementTool.getDdlTransactionIsolator(HibernateSchemaManagementTool.java:175)
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaValidator.doValidation(AbstractSchemaValidator.java:59)
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:191)
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:72)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:312)
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:460)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:892)
        ... 29 more
```

Comment: Why are you reconfiguring everything manually, and why are you trying to use JTA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`NoJtaPlatform`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/engine/transaction/jta/platform/internal/NoJtaPlatform.html) indicates that you've not set `hibernate.transaction.jta.platform`.

> The non-configured form of JTA platform. This is what is used if none was set up.

In Spring Boot this should be set by `HibernateJpaConfiguration`. If you're configuring the `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` yourself then you will need to do this manually.

I'm not sure why you're defining your own JPA beans (or overriding all the pom dependencies). If you deleted them all then it would just start working.

```xml
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.5.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc14</artifactId>
        <version>10.2.0.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: 'jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl'
    username: data_integration
    password: secret
  jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto: validate
  mvc.view:
    prefix: /WEB-INF/pages/
    suffix: .jsp
```

The only difference with this config is that the static path is `/static/**`, not `/static_content/**`, but I see no reason not to switch to the default.

If you actually want to use JTA (though you've only got one datasource and no JMS, so I don't see why) you'll need a standalone provider because Tomcat doesn't have one. Either add `spring-boot-starter-jta-atomikos` or `spring-boot-starter-jta-bitronix`.

Comment: Thanks for reply. In this case i don't need to use JTA. It was long time ago and it's was my first project. After your reply i checked my code again and found my mistake in entityManagerFactory.setJtaDataSource(dataSource) instead of entityManagerFactory.setDataSource(dataSource). Need to be more attentive:)